# When I start a Windows 10 Hyper-V Linux virtual machine, without an external internet connection, how can I SSH and HTTP connect to it?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, hyper-v, hypervisor

**Situation**

I have a Windows 10 laptop computer that I sometimes use on the road and would like to be able to do Linux development locally when there is no internet connection. I have set up a CentOS Virtual Machine for this purpose, installing all the needed software. The problem is, when the laptop can't get an internet address, then the Linux Virtual Machine does not have one either so I can't SSH or otherwise connect to it.

If I try to SSH to 127.0.0.1, I am only trying to connect to the Windows 10 operating system, not the virtual machine.

**Setup**

I have created a CentOS Virtual Machine using Windows 10 Hyper-V Manger. I have set up a network connection for it using the Virtual Switch Manager.

[image: VM network switch for Linux]

This works great as long as the laptop computer has an internet connection. The VM has an IP address that I set in the network scripts. I can SSH and HTTP connect to this address.

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:01:07:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.140/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe01:701/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

However, if the laptop does not have network connectivity, then the VM does not have the hard-coded IP address that I set in the network script.

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:01:07:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I have tried starting the VM using an Internal Switch. Then, the CentOS system retains the IP address specified (192.168.1.140). But the laptop computer can not ssh to it, giving an error "No Route to Host".

Is there a way to connect to this Virtual Machine via SSH, HTTP, etc when the laptop has no external internet connection?

Comment: Without an router, you need to set a static network route on your windows machine. https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/adding-a-tcpip-route-to-the-windows-routing-table/ Also use static ip on both "machines", they don't need to be in the same network, because they are already not in the same network. PS maybe you also need to set a static network route onto your linux machine.

Comment: PS give the _Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)_ a try, it works very well.

Comment: Thanks for the notion about the Linux subsystem. I started setting that up, then realized I need to run a LOT of software ( apache server, database, etc ) for development that I don't want running all the time in the background. It is only on rare occasion I need to do offline work. I'll try your suggestion above and see what happens.

Comment: You don't need to run the _WSL_ all the time, you may also stop it. Additionally you could also create a small Linux bash script, which start/stops all the heavy background daemons/services. PS look this cool X-server for Windows 10: [https://x410.dev/](https://x410.dev/)

Comment: Okay, you have sufficiently illuminated this issue to give me a path to follow. The WSL-installed LAMP services can be accessed via localhost according to this article. I'll try setting that up as the solution to this problem.  https://4sysops.com/archives/install-lamp-stack-apache-mysql-php-on-the-subsystem-for-linux-2-wsl2/

I'll also have to experiment with Docker, since I'd like the developed software to be portable.